# Python 3.4 email ContentManager - how to use?

Tags: email, python-3.x

I may get slammed because this question is too broad, but anyway I going to ask cause what else do I do? Digging through the Python source code should surely give me enough "good effort" points to warrant helping me?

I am trying to use Python 3.4's new email content manager http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.contentmanager.html#content-manager-instances

It is my understanding that this should allow me to read an email message, then be able to access all the email header fields and body as UTF-8, without going through the painful process of decoding from whatever weird encoding back into clean UTF-8.  I understand is also handles parsing of date headers and email address headers.  Generally making life easier for reading emails in Python.  Great stuff, very interesting.

However I am a beginner programmer - there are no examples in the current documentation of how to start from the start.  I need a simple example showing how to read an email file and using the new email content manager, read back the header fields, address fields and body/

I have dug into the python 3.4 source code and looked at the tests for the email content manager. I will admit to being sufficiently amatuerish that I was too confused to be able to glean enough from the tests to start writing my own simple example.

So, is anyone willing to help with a simple example of how to use the Python 3.4 email content manager to read the header fields and body and address fields of an email?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

First: the “address fields” in an email are in fact simply headers whose names have been agreed upon in standards, like `To` and `From`. So all you need are the email headers and body and you are done.

Given a modern `contentmanager`-powered `EmailMessage` instance such as Python 3.4 returns if you specify a policy (like `default`) when reading in an email message, you can access its auto-decoded headers by treating it like a Python dictionary, and its body with the `get_body()` call. Here is an example script I wrote that does both maneuvers in a safe and standard way:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/fopnp/blob/m/py3/chapter12/display_email.py

Behind the scenes, the policy is what is really in charge of what happens to both headers and content — with the `default` policy automatically subjecting headers to the encoding and decoding functions in `email.utils`, and content to the logic you asked about that is inside of `contentmanager`.

But as the caller you usually will not need to know the behind-the-scenes magic, because headers will “just work” and content can be easily accessed through the methods illustrated in the above script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an email in a file and want to read it into Python, it's the [`email.Parser` you should probably look at](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.parser.html#parser-class-api) first. [Like Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697432/923794), I don't quite see the need for using the `contentmanager`, but maybe your question *is* too broad and you need to help me understand it better.

Code could look like:

```
filename = 'your_file_here.email.txt'

import email.parser
with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
  message = email.parser.Parser().parse(fh)
```

There are even convenience functions, and the one for your case would be:

```
import email
message = email.message_from_file('your_file_here.email.txt')
```

Then check the [docs on email.message](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.message.html) to see how to access the message's content. You can check with `is_multipart()` if it's a single monolithic block of text, or a MIME message consisting of multiple parts. In the latter case, there's `walk()` to iterate over each part.